# ASP.NET WEB API PUT method Nullreference Exception

Tags: json, asp.net-web-api, http-put

I'm trying to pass an object named "User" with user data in HTTP PUT method. I've created a custom controller method, gave it a [HttpPut]. In my application i'm calling a proper route with PUT header, but when i'm trying to pass an User object in JSON format my WEB API is throwing nullreference exception, which indicates that user object isn't passed. MY other custom POST methods are working fine, I'm having problem only with PUT method. My object in JSON format has proper formatting, I double-checked. What may be causing the problem?

Comment: Have you checked that there's a `[FromBody]` attribute in front of the parameter? Are you sending a `Content-Type: application/json` Header?

Comment: @Henrik-Ilgen Yes, I've set Header in my request. I also tried to add [FromBody] Tag to my parameter in controller, but problem remains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix the problem. In my User model constructor i deleted initialization of lists of other objects and  it worked.